# How to adjust analysis timeout through UI

Tags: visual-studio, code-contracts

Is there a way to adjust the analysis timeout through the [Code Contracts Editor Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/02de7066-b6ca-42b3-8b3c-2562c7fa024f) UI? If not, is there some other way to tweak this setting from within Visual Studio? I don't see any calls to cccheck in the .csproj file so I'm unclear on how it's integrated into the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify additional command line options for cccheck.exe in Project properties > Code Contracts (tab) > Extra Static Checker Options.

[image: Screenshot]